# cin a character array from user using new C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, input

I need to create `Title` (it is a data member of a class) which is a string of variable size and it is dynamically created and defaults to an empty string.

In a class i created a member function `setTitle()` that prompts the user to enter a title,
it's as the following:

```
Book &setTitle()
{ 
    char *title="";//the array that is supposed to hold the input
    cout << "Title: ";
    cin >> title;//take the input
    Title = new char[strlen(title)+1];//create a char array for Title of size same as title with an additional for '\0'
    assert(Title != 0);
    strcpy(Title, title);//copying content of title to Title
    cout << Title;
    return *this;
}
```

When I run this it give me no error, but when I put  a value for `Title` it stops responding. So I need to know how to accept input from user into a character pointer (or whatever it's called, here it is the line `cin >> title;`).

Comment: You're reading into a string literal. That's undefined behaviour. You're either going to have to read into something like `std::string` or recreate its behaviour if you want any input size to be ok.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading from the input stream into a string literal. That's not a good idea because it will select the following overload:

```
basic_istream& operator>>( void*& value );
```

which is not supposed to be used with C-strings (which should be `const`).

You should use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead:

```
Book& setTitle() {
    std::string title;
    std::cout << "Title: ";
    std::cin >> title;
    Title = title;
    std::cout << Title;
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
char *title="";//
```

you define a pointer that points to a string literal that contains only the terminating zero. In C++ string literals have types of constant character arrays. So it would be more correctly to write

```
const char *title="";//
```

Also you may not change string literals even if you will define the pointer without qualifier const.

There are two approaches. Either you use class `std::string`  instead of pointer Title or you use a local character array in the function read data in it and allocate pointer Title according to the length of the inputted data and copy the character array to it. For example

```
Book &setTitle()
{
    const size_t N = 100;
    char title[N]; 

    cout << "Title: ";
    cin.getline( title, N );

    Title = new char[strlen(title)+1];//create a char array for Title of size same as title with an additional for '\0'
    assert(Title != 0);
    strcpy(Title, title);//copying content of title to Title
    cout << Title;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: So const size_t N = 100;(and by the way i dnt know what size_t is) and char title[N]; are equivalent to title[100]? Im just asking that because im trying to run away from the cin.getline()